# Windows Low-Level keyboard hook, allow (Win + H) not other Win + hotkeys

Tags: winapi, keyhook

We have a kiosk app where we would like to allow use of the <kbd>Win + H</kbd> hotkey to bring up Voice Typing, but still filter out other <kbd>Win + ...</kbd> hotkeys and the <kbd>Win</kbd> key by itself.

The hook is set with `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, callback, hInstance, 0);`

Log from pressing <kbd>Win + H</kbd>:

```
// w = bool, GetAsyncKeyState for left and right windows keys
// h = bool, ...for "h" key
// key = KBDLLHOOKSTRUCY* pkh->vkCode,  72 = h, 91 = left Windows key
// flags = KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* pkh->flags
// pressed Windows, then H, then released
w=0  h=0  key= 91  flags = 1
w=-1  h=0  key= 91  flags = 1
... repeats ....
w=-1  h=0  key= 91  flags = 1
w=-1  h=0  key= 72  flags = 0 
w=-1  h=-1  key= 72  flags = 80
w=-1  h=0  key= 91  flags = 81
```

What I'm finding while trying different permutations of code in the callback is, either I get no keypress, or I get a plain `h` (so Voice Typing is not launched), or all other <kbd>Win + ...</kbd> hotkeys get through not just <kbd>Win + H</kbd>.

This treats the press as a plain `h`, so apparently at least some of the <kbd>Win</kbd> key events before the `h` events must be allowed past the filter:

```cpp
if (nCode == HC_ACTION) 
{
    BOOL bWinKeyDown = (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LWIN) >> 15) | (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RWIN) >> 15);
    if (pkh->vkCode == 'H')
    {
        // w=-1  h=0  key= 72  flags = 0 
        // w=-1  h=-1  key= 72  flags = 80
        return CallNextHookEx(g_hHookKbdLL, nCode, wp, lp);
    }
    else if ((pkh->vkCode == VK_LWIN || pkh->vkCode == VK_RWIN))
    {
        // also just "h" if we allow through the w=-1  h=0  key= 91  flags = 1 events
        // if ((bWinKeyDown && (pkh->flags == 1))   )
        //    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHookKbdLL, nCode, wp, lp);
        //  else
        return -1;
    }
}
return CallNextHookEx(g_hHookKbdLL, nCode, wp, lp);
```

This lets all <kbd>Win + ...</kbd> hotkeys through, it seems like the first event acts as a "dead key" that gets applied to any next letter key:

```
if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
{
    BOOL bWinKeyDown = (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LWIN) >> 15) | (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RWIN) >> 15);
    if (pkh->vkCode == 'H')
    {
        // w=-1  h=0  key= 72  flags = 0 
        // w=-1  h=-1  key= 72  flags = 80
        return CallNextHookEx(g_hHookKbdLL, nCode, wp, lp);
    }
    else if ((pkh->vkCode == VK_LWIN || pkh->vkCode == VK_RWIN))
    {
        if ((!bWinKeyDown && (pkh->flags == 1))) // // w=0  h=0  key= 91  flags = 1 - first event in log
            return CallNextHookEx(g_hHookKbdLL, nCode, wp, lp);
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

Is there any way to trap all <kbd>Win + ...</kbd> hotkey except for <kbd>Win + H</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, `win+h` produces four messages, Index 1 to 4.
[image]
You can trap them at the second message. The following code which traps all `Win+...` hotkey except for `win+h` works for me.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Proc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* s= (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        std::cout << " Index=" << nwinhooksdll++ << "wParam="<< wParam <<" s->vkCode=" << s->vkCode << " s->scanCode=" << s->scanCode << " s->flags=" << s->flags << " s->dwExtraInfo=" << s->dwExtraInfo << "\n";
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LWIN))
        {
            if (s->vkCode == 'H')
            {

           }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Update:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* s = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        std::cout << " Index=" << nwinhooksdll++ << "wParam=" << wParam << " s->vkCode=" << s->vkCode << " s->scanCode=" << s->scanCode << " s->flags=" << s->flags << " s->dwExtraInfo=" << s->dwExtraInfo << "\n";
        static BOOL H = FALSE;
        static BOOL Other = FALSE;
        static BOOL Send = FALSE;
        if (Send) {
            Send = FALSE;
            INPUT inputs = {};
            inputs.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inputs.ki.wVk = VK_LWIN;
            inputs.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            UINT uSent = SendInput(1, &inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LWIN) >> 15) {
            if (s->vkCode == 'H') {
                H = TRUE;
            }
            else if (s->vkCode == 91) {
                if (H || Other)
                {
                    H = FALSE;
                    Other = FALSE;
                    Send = TRUE;
                    std::cout << "return 1\n";
                    return 1;
                }else{

                }
            }else{ 
                Other = TRUE;
                if (wParam == 256) { 
                    std::cout << "return 1\n";
                    return 1; 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Update 2:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Proc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        if (wParam > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "sent by the current thread wParam=" << wParam;
        }
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* s= (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

        std::cout << " Index=" << nwinhooksdll++ << "wParam="<< wParam <<" s->vkCode=" << s->vkCode << " s->scanCode=" << s->scanCode << " s->flags=" << s->flags << " s->dwExtraInfo=" << s->dwExtraInfo << "\n";

        static BOOL H = FALSE;
        static BOOL Other = FALSE;
        static BOOL Send = FALSE;
        //TODO
        if (Send)
        {
            Send = FALSE;
            if (s->vkCode != 91 && s->scanCode != 0 && wParam == 256)
            {
                if (!H && !Other)
                {
                    INPUT inputs = {};
                    inputs.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                    inputs.ki.wVk = s->vkCode;
                    inputs.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                    UINT uSent = SendInput(1, &inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
                }

                INPUT inputs = {};
                inputs.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                inputs.ki.wVk = VK_LWIN;
                inputs.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                UINT uSent = SendInput(1, &inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
            }
        }

        H = FALSE;
        Other = FALSE;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LWIN)>>15 && s->scanCode != 0)
        {
            if (s->vkCode == 'H')
            {
                H = TRUE;
            }
            else if (s->vkCode == 91)
            {
                    if (wParam == 257)
                    {
                        if (s->scanCode !=0)
                        {
                            Send = TRUE;
                            std::cout << "return 1\n";
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                Other = TRUE;
                if (wParam == 256)
                {
                    std::cout << "return 1\n";
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: This works, except for me in WIn 11 Pro after I hit Win + H, all other (normal) keys are ignored even though an edit field has focus with a blinking cursor.  Can you replicate that?

Comment: I have updated my code. The change is mainly to compensate a `win` key up message.

Comment: The updated answer fixes the dead keyboard problem, but unfortunately it lets through the Win key by itself, giving access to the Start menu.  Kiosk apps are hard :)

Comment: My code goal is to let through the Win key by itself because your question said trapping all `Win + ...` hotkey except for `Win + H`. It's easy to modify.

Comment: I've updated the first paragraph to be more clear.  Can you update your answer to also block Win by itself?  It's working great aside from that.

Comment: I have updated my code to achieve this with my best, but you may need to fine tune it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a test for `WM_KEYDOWN` and add test when `Win+` key is down and `H` is pressed down.

Returning non-zero value is not recommended, and the code below ends up eating a message, which is no good. But this is only eating the message for key down state. So everything should be okay once that key is released.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK kbd_proc(int nCode, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* pkh = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lp;
        BOOL bWinKeyDown = (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LWIN) >> 15) | 
                    (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RWIN) >> 15);
        if (pkh->vkCode != 'H' && wp == WM_KEYDOWN && bWinKeyDown)
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"not Win+H...\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHookKbdLL, nCode, wp, lp);
}
```

Comment: This would work for Notepad or other normal processes.  The problem is that Windows Voice Typing is an OS feature, like Win by itself brings up Start, and I haven't found a way to launch Voice Typing other than letting Win + H flow through to the OS from native C++.

Comment: Use `pkh->vkCode != 'H'` to allow Win+H and stop other messages. Don't do anything when Win+H is pressed. I have Windows 11 and it works as expected, maybe it's a different setup.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it in the morning when I'm back at work

Comment: This almost works.  It blocks other win + _ hotkeys, except for win by itself.  We need to block the start menu.