# How can I catch a keybind like F6 no matter what is in focus with c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

Preferably with `<windows.h>`, but if it's not possible I am open to other solutions.

I've seen `RegisterHotKey()`, but it requires <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or <kbd>Win</kbd> to be pressed.

I would also like to be able to know when the key has been let go (is not being pressed anymore).

Comment: To snoop on keyboard messages across all processes you need a low-level keyboard hook in a DLL.  Your app might also need to run with admin rights to see presses in other apps running as admin.

Comment: @DaveS the `SetWindowsHookEx()` low-level hooks (`WH_MOUSE_LL` and `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`) do not require a DLL, as they are not injected into other processes, they always run in the thread that installs them.

Comment: For you application or the whole system ? Have you considered an accelerator table (if for your application only) ?

Comment: RegisterHotKey doesn't require a modifier key, you can pass 0 for the `fsModifiers` arg.

Comment: Interpret them in *LowLevelKeyboardProc* hook procedure, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75061028/windows-low-level-keyboard-hook-allow-win-h-not-other-win-hotkeys.

Answer (score 2):

To monitor the keyboard globally, you can either:

- use a [`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelkeyboardproc) hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw).
- use the [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) API to receive [`WM_INPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-input) messages.

Comment: Regarding the need for a DLL, Doesn't the table at the bottom of your link say "WH_KEYBOARD_LL Global only", "WH_MOUSE_LL Global only" or am I misreading what that means?

Comment: @DaveS the `LL` hooks can be used only globally, yes. But [they don't require a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276756/65863), unlike the other global hooks, which do.

Comment: Thanks, I trusted the MS docs too much.

Comment: @DaveS In fairness, this can be inferred from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelkeyboardproc): *"This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it."* This is also why low-level hooks are extremely disruptive. For every input event, the system walks the entire hook chain, switching to the thread that installed the hook, runs the callback, and moves to the next callback only after the previous has returned. Unless you must *filter* input, use Raw Input. It's far less intrusive.