# How to Detect Single Space Key Presses in a Low-Level Keyboard Hook Without Timer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've broken my arm and am developing a one-handed keyboard application for Windows that mirrors the keyboard layout when the space bar is held down, allowing for one-handed typing. The mirroring function is operational using a timer, but this is not ideal - it's sluggish and leaves a space if a mirrored key is pressed quickly after holding space down.

Is there a better way to handle this use case? I've tried using flags from the lParam's [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-kbdllhookstruct?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but I cannot find a way to differentiate single key presses from repeated. I've also tried ignoring input on space keydowns and sending an input when it's just a single press, but I run into issues of it not working, likely due to infinite loops.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <map>

using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
std::chrono::time_point<Clock> spacePressedTime;
bool spaceHeld = false;
std::map<DWORD, DWORD> keyMappings;

bool SendMirroredKeyPress(UINT vkCode);
void InitializeKeyMappings();

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        auto kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        if (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_SPACE) {
            switch (wParam) {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                if (!spaceHeld) { // Check if this is the first event of space bar press
                    spacePressedTime = Clock::now();
                    spaceHeld = true; // Prevent re-entry for this press
                }
                return 1; // Block this event to prevent default space input
            case WM_KEYUP:
                if (spaceHeld) {
                    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(Clock::now() - spacePressedTime).count();
                    if (elapsed < 200) { // Threshold for distinguishing tap from hold
                        // It was a tap, simulate a space key press
                        INPUT input[2] = {};
                        input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                        input[0].ki.wVk = VK_SPACE;
                        input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                        input[1].ki.wVk = VK_SPACE;
                        input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                        SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));
                        std::cout << "Space pressed normally.\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        // It was a hold, so enter or stay in mirror mode without inserting a space
                        std::cout << "Leaving mirror mode.\n";
                    }
                    spaceHeld = false; // Reset for the next press
                    return 1; // Block the event to prevent default handling
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // For other keys, check if space is held (mirror mode active) and handle accordingly
            if (spaceHeld && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)) {
                if (SendMirroredKeyPress(kbdStruct.vkCode)) {
                    return 1; // Block the original key press
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

bool SendMirroredKeyPress(UINT vkCode) {
    auto it = keyMappings.find(vkCode);
    if (it != keyMappings.end()) {
        INPUT input[1] = {};
        input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input[0].ki.wVk = it->second; // Mirrored virtual key code

        // Send the mirrored key press
        SendInput(1, input, sizeof(INPUT));

        // Indicate that the original key press should be blocked
        return true;
    }
    // No mirroring needed for this key
    return false;
}

static void InitializeKeyMappings() {
    keyMappings[0x4E] = 0x42; // N to B as example
}

int main() {
    InitializeKeyMappings();

    HHOOK hhkLowLevelKybd = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "Hook set. Press and hold space to enter mirror mode. Tap space for normal input. N should switch to b in mirror mode.\n";

    MSG msg;
    while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhkLowLevelKybd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it physically takes time to distinguish between two states that have the same initial starting sequence then you cannot hope to get a result before that time has expired. If you are unhappy with that situation, build a time machine.

Comment: SendInput() will get the callback to run again, I guess that's what the question is really about.  Check the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT.flags field for LLKHF_INJECTED.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-kbdllhookstruct

Comment: *a way to differentiate single key presses from repeated*. Maintain a variable indicating the last pressed space key. The variable will be reset when other keys are pressed, and you can check the variable when a space key is pressed to see if it's repeated.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment, a way to differentiate single key presses from repeated is maintaining a variable indicating the last pressed key if it's space key or not. The variable will be reset when other keys are pressed, and you can check the variable when a space key is pressed to see if it's repeated. For example, see the variable `static BOOL H = FALSE;` of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75066399/15511041).